# how to call a method in the knockout $.getJSON()

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have this basic knockout script set up (still learning)

```
$.getJSON(clientUrl + "/list/" + 1, function (data) {

var viewModel = {
    clients: ko.observableArray(data)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

The first argument 'lucidServer.getClients(1)' makes a call to this ajax request:

```
var getClients = function (id) {
    return $.ajax(clientUrl + "/list/" + id)
};
```

Now I am getting the json back, but it does not seem to be binding correctly the the template. Here is the json:

```
0: {iD:1, userId:1, name:CompanySoft, LLC.,…}
1: {iD:2, userId:1, name:Widget Factory,…}
2: {iD:3, userId:1, name:Jim's Consulting,…}
```

ANd the template is here:

```
<div id="clientListOutput">
            <ul "template: { foreach: clients }">
                <li><span data-bind"text: name"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? Doing an AJAX request and then doing another request right away?

Comment: perhaps not, but I am unsure of the best practice to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: love your avatar ! Just realized how much I miss Zelda (original) :p

Comment: What **do** you want to do? Isn't the `$.getJSON` call enough? Like `$.getJSON(clientUrl + "/list/" + 1)`? Or maybe have a function which returns the url instead of actually doing a request.

Comment: Ya ok, I think I understand now, let me update the code, which lead me to another question that I will add the the edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of typos in your markup.

The HTML should look like:

```
  <div id="clientListOutput">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: clients">
                <li><span data-bind="text: name"></span></li>
            </ul>
  </div>
```

As you have markup inside your `ul` tags you don't need to use the `template` binding.  Just use a `foreach` and Knockout will do the work to iterate over each client and render the `li` for each one.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/6XhM4/